# Does typing to Cortana make her behave differently?

Tags: 8.1, cortana

I'm at work right now and I wanted to quietly use Cortana. I tried typing a question to her but she's just bing searching everything I say. I even tried one of the "Try..." suggestions (Show me highly rated restaurants near me) and she just bing searched it. She was able to comprehend "remind me to..." but she would just bing everything else.

Does she behave differently when you type to her? When I use her at home, I talk to her, and she works great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience she behaves the same. The only difference is that she is quiet - just silently writing you back.

To be specific: I just wrote "*How are you?*" to her and her response was "*Quite well, thanks for asking.*".

Comment: I don't thing so. Just tried "turn wifi off" and it just search the web. But if I'm speaking with her the WiFi is turned off.

Comment: Even turning wifi on/off is working for me (both ways-speaking and writing).

Comment: What exactly did you type? I was trying exactly as above, with no punctuation.

Comment: Exactly as above... :) No punctuation. So this seems like bug or settings deviation maybe...

Comment: Damn it. Tried again and it just worked.

Answer (score 2):

Cortana Bing searches everything if you're typing at a search page.

## At a search page

What I mean by search page is a Bing search page with tabs on top, like the page for the query "what color is the sky".

Typed queries into the search box of a search page will result in just more search pages. E.g., "open internet explorer".

In contrast, voice commands always return you to the home page instead of a search page, so they give you the less Bing-y results if possible.

## Not at a search page

If you don't give commands at a search page, voice and typing give the same result, except that typing doesn't give auditory responses.

If you type a command to Cortana, be sure to spell it right. It seems that Cortana can't give non-search pages to slightly misspelled typed queries, like "open internet ezplorer".